# Wsapi Version Issues in Debug Mode

Tags: sdk, rally

I've noticed that there is an issue with RC1 in debug mode where if I don't specify the "wsapiVersion" property as '1.43' I will get this error back from the server:

"Uncaught Invalid model type specified: ..."

It's not a huge inconvenience but when I'm working with objects like the 'rallyiterationcombobox' I can't set this property which forces me to test my apps in the production version of Rally. Is this a known bug with the debug version of the RC1 SDK?

Comment: Which model are you trying to get?  I've used the 'rallyiterationcombobox' without troubles in SDK 2.0rc1, and without specifying the "wsapiVersion" as '1.43'.

Comment: It happens for any model that I query for using the WSAPI. In this case the model is Iteration since it's trying to load the records for the 'rallyiterationcombobox'.

Comment: Do you get any other errors in the console and/or the network tab?  This may be related to the issues with timing out on the call to the super slow schema endpoint...

Comment: I think that is correct Kyle. I get an undefined callback error as well.

Comment: Seems like some difference in the way the jsonp calls are handled wrt timeouts and error handling.  I'll file a defect to investigate this.